# The mediaelement.js overlay button on mobile displays incorrectly

Tags: wordpress, css, mediaelement.js

I've done several hours of troubleshooting, and a couple more searching for an answer, couldn't find any, although found some other people with the same problem.

The problem is that when I try and load the page ( [http://reinbeerclub.com/](http://reinbeerclub.com) ) on a mobile device (tried android and iphone) the play button goes to the left upper corner and it stops working. so when pressed it doesn't play the video.

i am using the [yootheme](http://www.yootheme.com/themes) digit theme  wich is based on [uikit](http://www.getuikit.com/docs/components.html) on a wordpress site, and the MediaElement.js built in.
 the code I am using to display the video is:

```
            <video poster="/wp-content/uploads/video.gif" controls class="uk-responsive-width">
                <source type="video/youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tQE919Uc0E0" />
            </video>
```

(basic HTML5) but I can't get it to work on mobile devices.. can anyone help?

Here is a screenshot [image: screenshot]